# Why am I getting "Form elements do not have associated labels" even though there's a label associated with the input?

Tags: html, accessibility, lighthouse

I have this code this react code

```
const Icon = styled.div`...`
const ToggleInput = styled.input`...`
const Lines = styled.label`...`
const Line = styled.div`...`

return (
  <Icon>
    <ToggleInput
      id="NavigationMenuToggler"
      name="NavigationMenuToggler"
      role="button"
      aria-controls={DOMConfig.aria.mobileMenu}
      type="checkbox" />
    <Lines for="NavigationMenuToggler" aria-controls="MobileNavigationMenu">
      <Line />
      <Line />
      <Line />
    </Lines>
  </Icon>
)
```

which generates this HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="NavigationMenuToggler" name="NavigationMenuToggler" role="button" aria-controls="MobileNavigationMenu" class="sc-jffIyK kktnkO">
  <label for="NavigationMenuToggler" aria-controls="MobileNavigationMenu" class="sc-gSYCTC eRjJOo"></label>
</div>
```

The label's `for` attribute is equal to the input's id. In lighthouse, however, I'm still seeing the "Form elements do not have associated labels" warning. Why is this happening?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you sure there's not another input on the page that this is referring to?

Comment: I agree with @RobinZigmond.  The generated HTML code does not have a label problem so Lighthouse might be complaining about a different element.  However, you do have some weird code with `<input type="checkbox">` but then you also specify `role="button"`.  That will be very confusing to assistive tech users.  A checkbox is a toggle that you can check on/off.  A button is an immediate action thing.  What's the point of using `type="checkbox"` if you're overriding the semantics with a `role`?  Either remove the role or use `<input type="button">` or `<button>`.

Comment: As per @quentinC - the issue was the <label> being empty (as in - no actual text). To fix that I switched Lines to be a div and then I created new Label component that does have some text and I visually hid it from the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<label>` is present and is correctly linked to the `<input>`, but it is completely empty.
As a consequence, it is like if it was not present.

Your label must have some text content, so that screen readers can say something when landing on the input.
If you don't want that text to be displayed on screen, you can send it off screen, by using the visually hidden text technique.
Alternatively, you can add a an attribute aria-label on the input, which must also be non-empty for the same reason.